# Merge two Different fields result django Query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model from which I want to get data in a same  object(JSON)
I have this model

```
class Suggestion(models.Model):
   city = models.CharField(max_length=250 , null=True , blank=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250 , null=True , blank=True)
```

Now I will query like this

```
           name = Suggestion.objects.filter(name__icontains=search)
           city = Suggestion.objects.filter(city__icontains=search)
           Name=nameSeilizerr(activities,many=True)
           serializer=CitySeilizer(city,many=True)
```

In serializer I will send only name in Nameserializer and city in city Serilizer.

Main Concept is I want to suggestion to user either its Name or city name in field. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `Q` objects to search for `Suggestion`s where the `name` or the `city` matches (or both):

```
from django.db.models import Q

suggestions = Suggestion.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=search) |
    Q(city__icontains=search)
)
serializer=CitySerializer(suggestions, many=True)
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Actually I need just 1 variable in json like {suggestion :  'City or Name'}   . ln this way I will get  both city and Name I guess in diff variables  .

Comment: Like if I put  America  I should get  per object single suggestion word

Comment: @gamer: this is *one* queryset that contains the `Suggestion`s that match one of the two conditions. So if both `name` and `city` match, that `Suggestion` will be in the queryset once, so this is the only query you need to perform.

Comment: Sorry Sir If I am unable to convey let me give a small example , I have a search box if a user type any text it will show suggestion either a Name or City Name ,

Comment: @gamer: no, it will show suggestions where the `name` matches, or the `city` (name) matches, or both. So the serializer will simply serialize *all* objects that match one of these, our both.

Comment: Yes , Got your point I need to send suggestion in List of string I think , till now I found that .